# How to use Equal for close arbitrary precision numbers to be considered the same?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, code-request, arbitrary-precision

I am trying to add a comparator function in a larger piece of code which can equate two arbitrary precision numbers and yields `True` if they are approximately close.

My goal is to use such a function to select only those triangles from a list of triangles that contain my point/vertex of interest. All coordinates of the triangles are described to a Precision=8.

The data for the variable can be accessed at the dropbox link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1kv5ks3duwk9ea/smallexample.mx?dl=0

Two variables can be loaded from `smallexample.mx` file: `vertex` and `listofTri`.

The comparator function is provided below. Essentially, `listofTri` - an association that comprises of three keys and each key associates several triangles - is mapped to `GroupBy`. A check is made to determine whether the triangles contain `vertex` as a member. All the triangles that are grouped together as `True` are then extracted.

```
(*my code*)
$assoctri = <|GroupBy[Flatten[#, 1], MemberQ[#, x_ /; x == vertex] &][True] & /@ listofTri|>;//AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0003498, Null}*)
```

**the problem**

Although this function is fast for my application (for 1760 different vertices, finishes in 0.6 seconds) there is a case where the simple code may not be ideal especially since I am utilizing arbitrary precision for calculation; case when the points are in close proximity. `Equal` will not work in such circumstances. For instance, consider this example where the first coordinate in both lists differ in the 7th decimal place (of precision 8 numbers).

```
{1.171397258142043033742927800409`8.*^-8, 
  11.362048795583818972`8., -1.0085014716116476041`8.} == \
{1.171397058142043033742927800409`8.*^-8, 
  11.362048795583818972`8., -1.0085014716116476041`8.}

(*False*)
```

We can trick `Equal` by relaxing the Internal`$EqualTolerance to get True

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = #},
   {1.171397258142043033742927800409`8.*^-8, 
     11.362048795583818972`8., -1.0085014716116476041`8.} == \
{1.171397058142043033742927800409`8.*^-8, 
     11.362048795583818972`8., -1.0085014716116476041`8.}
   ] & /@ {2, 3}

(*{False,True}*)
```

So the only way I can think of is to encapsulate the first code in a `Block` and relax  Internal`$EqualTolerance so that Equal yields True for approximately close points (like this).

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = tolerance},
 <|GroupBy[Flatten[#, 1], MemberQ[#, x_ /; x == vertex] &][True] & /@listofTri|>
 ]
```

Despite having read other posts, I am pretty confused as to how Internal`$EqualTolerance works.

**Q.** Is there a way to use Internal`$EqualTolerance to relax Equal such that any two arbitrary precision numbers (e.g. 13.XXXXXX or 0.XXXXX) - are considered equal if 5 digits to the right of the decimal are say the same?

**Other attempts**

Moreover, as background it is important to note that I have considered using the following functions. These implementations were slower for what I desire.

```
<|GroupBy[Flatten[#,1],MemberQ[#,x_ /;Chop[x-vertex,10^-5]=={0,0,0}] &][True]&/@listofTri|>;//AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.001297, Null}*)

<|GroupBy[Flatten[#,1],MemberQ[#,x_ /;Norm[x-vertex]<10^-5] &][True]&/@listofTri|>;//AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.00278, Null}*)
```

**Q.** Is there a better way to make faster function than what has been presented above? (new function or modification of above function perhaps?)

Comment: Consider as an example the function `Round` and use its second argument: ```Round[0.000033493, 10^-7] == Round[0.0000335, 10^-7]```

Comment: `Equal` always compares the most significant bits. It could compare the 5 most significant digits, or the $n$ most significant digits. To make $n$ correspond to 5 decimal places, you'd have to the adjust the tolerance for each comparison. The tolerance would have to depend on the both the magnitudes and precisions of both numbers. I'm not sure what `Equal` does when those parameters are different.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see. I am actually quite stumped at the moment. The code took some time to develop and now i am pretty much stuck with how to handle this numerical problem. Do you think  `MemberQ[#,x_ /;Chop[x-vertex,10^-5]=={0,0,0}]`  is the way to go? If yes, can the implementation be changed/sped up?

Comment: How about `Equal @@ SetAccuracy[{tri1, tri2}, 5]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 in each comparison i am comparing a vertex with a triangle. how would you change it then since both your args are tri? maybe i did not understand how it works. Can you kindly show an example. thanks !

Comment: @Syed i don't know whether this method is robust for usage. It may also be a costly operation

Comment: I wrote `tri1`, but I meant vertex. I was thinking to set the accuracy `x` and `vertex` to 5 in `x == vertex`. It might work if only one were set to 5, such as `vertex`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks. i understand now. you can choose to add the answer to the post.

Comment: You can make a comparison for your application and let us know; i.e., if time permits.

Comment: You might consider using `<=` with some prescribed epsilon. This can be applied either to the absolute or relative "distance". For example if you have points `p1` and `p2` you can check `With[{diff=p1-p2},diff.diff/(p1.p1+p2.p2)<eps]` to assess whether relative discrepancy between those points is small enough to regard them as equal.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks. in the context of the `Groupby` function above, how can I define the comparator using the metric that you have proposed. Would not this be timewise-costly operation?

Comment: Good point. I do not know the implementation details of `GroupBy` so I cannot say for certain. If it has ways of avoiding all-pairs comparisons when using `Equal` then my suggestion is likely to be relatively slower. This might take experimentation. Another possibility would be to avoid `GroupBy` and roll your own using `Nearest`.